# Issues in calculating tf-idf in gensim

Tags: python, gensim, tf-idf

I am using Gensim to calculate tf-idf scores for my corpus mentioned below.

```
corpus=['human interface computer',
 'survey user computer system response time',
 'eps user interface system',
 'system human system eps',
 'user response time']
```

My current code is as follows.

```
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(line.lower().split() for line in corpus)

class MyCorpus(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        for line in corpus:
            yield dictionary.doc2bow(line.lower().split())

corpus = MyCorpus()

tfidf = models.TfidfModel(corpus)

corpus_tfidf = tfidf[corpus]
```

However, I get the error `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object` (PS: if my code is wrong I am happy to have a different code). Please help me to calculate tf-idf values for my current corpus. Moreover, I want to get the 3 terms that has the highest tf-idf score in my corpus.

Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

Well you are redefining your original `corpus` list as a `MyCorpus` object, so of course this is going into an infinite recursion when trying to iterate over it (since you iterate over `corpus` in the `__iter__` method). Maybe you want to define `my_corpus = MyCorpus()`? Otherwise explain what you are trying to do...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I honestly want to calculate tf-idf values for my corpus and get the 3 terms that has the highest tf-idf score. Please let me know if you know how to do it?

Comment: Have you tried this fix? If i still doesn't work you need to explain why...

Comment: I get the following error after the fix: `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`

Comment: Then I think you should accept this answer and post new question reflecting your new problem, mentioning the line where the error is generated and the whole call stack...