# Ensemble LDA: How to find more than 1 stable topic?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, lda, ensemble-learning

I used LDA (Latent Dirichlet Allocation) algorithm to analyse corpus from [StackExchange database](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwi10uCnvJL8AhV-RmwGHec6DmQQFnoECBEQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fconsole.cloud.google.com%2Fmarketplace%2Fproduct%2Fstack-exchange%2Fstack-overflow&usg=AOvVaw3b3AF70UCH8KOYJAH6adZ9). LDA is not ideal because it has problem with reproducibility because it gives different topics suggestion with every execution, which make it unreliable from my point of view. After reading an [introduction for Ensemble LDA (eLDA) from Gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ensemblelda.html), eLDA addresses this problem by executing LDA models multiple times and only outputs stable topics, which are topics that are occur multiple times from multiple LDAs (to explain it in a very simplified way).

How I executed eLDAs are:

0. Filter (so that only questions with topic "security" are left) and preprocess the data from StackExchange. I use last 10 years data of Q&A from StackOverflow.
1. Do trial and error of normal LDA to get ideal hyper parameter (passes and iteration) so that most if not all documents have converged. I refer this step to [this documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/tutorials/run_lda.html).
2. With the optimal LDA parameters, I ran eLDA:

   ```
    corpus = self.doc_matrix
    dictionary = vectorizer.id2word.id2token
    topic_model_class = LdaModel
    ensemble_workers = 4
    num_models = 12
    distance_workers = 4
    num_topics = 50
    passes=20
    iterations=5000
    epsilon = 1
    eval_every=10

    self.estimator = EnsembleLda(
        corpus=corpus,
        id2word=dictionary,
        num_topics=num_topics,
        passes=passes,
        iterations=iterations,
        num_models=num_models,
        topic_model_class=topic_model_class,
        ensemble_workers=ensemble_workers,
        distance_workers=distance_workers,
        epsilon=epsilon,
        eval_every=eval_every
    )
   ```
3. The result is always only one stable topic. This is just too few stable topic for my purpose. After couple days, I doesn't manage to increase stable topic findings/ improve my eLDA.
   [image]

My goal: find trend or topics in StackOverflow questions that are related to topic "security".

My opinion: the finding should be more than just one stable topic, because in StackOverflow there are tags available for every questions. Tag by itself is a topic. Therefore it should find more than one stable topic.

Questions:

a. Can somebody point me a direction how to optimise my eLDA model so that it can find more than one stable topic?

b. Is my logic wrong to assume that there should be more than one stable topic? I could accept it if the data are very diverse. But since every StackOverflow question consists tags, I assume the finding should have > 1 stable topic.

Thank you for any advice.

#################################################################

Why did I choose epsilon=1?
I execute the following:

```
def optimize_ensembleLda(self):
    print('*** Optimize ensemble LDA model.')
    import numpy as np
    shape = self.estimator.asymmetric_distance_matrix.shape
    without_diagonal = self.estimator.asymmetric_distance_matrix[~np.eye(shape[0], dtype=bool)].reshape(shape[0], -1)
    print("Min, mean & max value of asymetric distance matrix:")
    print(without_diagonal.min(), without_diagonal.mean(), without_diagonal.max())
    new_epsilon = without_diagonal.max()
    self.estimator.recluster(eps=new_epsilon, min_samples=2, min_cores=2)
    return
```

I chose to use the maximum distance, because I am trying to get more stable topics.

#################################################################

After executing Erwan's suggestion from commentary (increasing num_models to e.g. 40), I got the following error:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

The error points to the eLDA model from under step 2 above.
I doubled the ensemble_worker but the problem is not fixed. I will keep increasing it and give update here.

#################################################################

I solved the `RecursionError` by increasing the Python recursion limit with:

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(int(len(self.ttda)*1.2))
```

inside my Gensim eLDA code...
The reason for this problem is my large corpus size and hence the large topic numbers.
Still my original problem still exists, after increasing `num_models` to 40, I still get one stable topic.

*I would appreciate very much, if someone can help me finding more than one stable topic with Ensemble LDA from Gensim.*

Comment: I didn't study the question as in detail as you so I'm not sure this is a correct answer, but I did a few experiments with Gensim eLDA as well. With my data I found that the number of models (`num_models`) is an important parameter, possibly causing the number of topics to be too low if it's low. I used a higher number (40) and was able to obtain a few dozens topics. Of course it's also important to set `num_topics` high enough as well.

Comment: Hallo @Erwan, thank you for your comment. I tried your suggestion but got RecursionError. I have added my Question after applying it. I hope you can help me further. Many thanks.

Comment: I would suspect that this is a similar problem to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47300015/issues-in-calculating-tf-idf-in-gensim), not directly related to ensembleLDA but to a mistake in one of your iterations over the corpus. If you don't find it it's better to open a new question.

Comment: @Erwan I solved the problem with RecursionError. It is not because mistake from my side, but Gensim eLDA needs some improvement to be able to process large corpus. To be more precise, I increased the Python Recursion Limit to -> sys.setrecursionlimit(int(len(self.ttda)*1.2)) After solving recursion problem and using 40 num_models, I still get one stable topic, hence my original problem is not yet solved...

Comment: I would appreciate if someone can help me finding out more than one stable topic...

Comment: Maybe it would be useful to run your process with a different corpus in order to see if you still obtain only one topic, because it might also be due to your data.

Comment: @Erwan thank you for your suggestion. I tried running a working eLDA example script from https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/tutorials/run_ensemblelda.html which can be found at the bottom of the page. After debugging (due to runtime Error by inserting if __name__: "__main__" with underscores.) and running it and increase the num_models to 80, I still got one stable topics. Can you send me a working Python script for eLDA that results multiple stable topics as output? I would be grateful to have at least one good example (with multiple stable topics as output) for eLDA.

Comment: Ok, mind that it's not really finished code but I put my scripts [here](https://github.com/erwanm/gensim-temporary). I included my preprocessing, just in case it's related. I have been running this on a 40-cores machine on a cluster, I don't know if this is related either? I remember that every time I tried with a single core it didn't work, but maybe I had other bugs at the time. Anyway, running it as shown in the readme on my data gave me reasonably good results with multiple topics. Good luck!

Comment: Hello Erwan, thank you for your codes. I applied some of your codes to my problem and still can't solve my problem. I will let my question open, just in case someone else has a clue how to solve it in the future.

Comment: ok, sorry that it sill doesn't work. I guess this points to something special about your data. In case you want to try a different library, I recently heard about [tomotopy](https://bab2min.github.io/tomotopy/v0.12.3/en/).

Comment: Is there no stack trace printed along with the recursion error?

Comment: if I remember correctly, choosing a huge epsilon will rather cluster all of your topics into a single one. Getting more stable topics is mostly a question of tuning the parameters of recluster. Since recluster doesn't take that long, doing a grid search might be a good idea.